# Get records whose column sum is as close to preset maximum as possible

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
id | duration
-------------
1  | 2999
2  | 3219
3  | 3129
4  | 319    
5  | 3405
6  | 3084
7  | 3450
8  | 3305
9  | 3485
10 | 3483
11 | 3445
12 | 3570
13 | 1712
```

I want to write a MYSQL query that will return as many rows as it takes to get the total sum of "duration" to be as close to 12000 as possible.  Essentially I want to keep track of the total sum of duration and if a row is going to cause the overall sum of duration then skip it and check the next one.  In the data above this would mean returning IDs 1,2,3,4 and 13.  I've looked for other posts about this but all the queries they propose return only ids 1,2,3,4 and then stop because id 5 would breach the limit of 12000 - but I need it to keep going and check if there are any records down the line that could still be added.

I know that I could just return all the rows and loop through the results in PHP and keep track of the total duration but I'd rather get this done in the query if possible for efficiency.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using `user-defined variables`:

```
select * 
from (
  select id, duration, 
    @overallsum:=@overallsum+duration overall, 
    @prevrunningsum:=@runningsum prevsum,
    @runningsum:=case when @runningsum+duration<12000 then @runningsum+duration
                      else @runningsum
                 end under12000
  from yourtable, (select @overallsum:=0, @runningsum:=0, @prevrunningsum:=0) t
  order by id) t
where prevsum != under12000
order by id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80682a/1)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use of SQL.  You can get the closest combination with up to, say, 6 ids as:

```
select *
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id left join
     t t3
     on t2.id < t3.id left join
     t t4
     on t3.id < t4.id left join
     t t5
     on t4.id < t5.id left join
     t t6
     on t5.id < t6.id
order by abs(12000,
             coalesce(t1.duration, 0) + coalesce(t2.duration, 0) + coalesce(t3.duration, 0), + coalesce(t4.duration, 0) + coalesce(t5.duration, 0) + coalesce(t6.duration, 0)
            )
limit 1;
```

This is not very efficient -- it is looking at all possible combinations.  With 13 items and combinations with up to 6 elements, it should finish in a finite amount of time.

Comment: Eventually I will have hundreds or thousands of rows in the table so I don't think this would work for me long term.